# Android WebView crashes when video ends on KitKat

Tags: android, webview

As the title states, when I play a `full-screen` video in the WebView (i.e. a YouTube video) and let it play all the way to the end, the WebView crashes with `VM Aborting` and `Fatal Signal 6 (SIGABRT)` errors as shown below:

```
01-06 15:36:38.489: W/dalvikvm(2940): Invalid indirect reference 0x10 in decodeIndirectRef
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41854ca8 self=0x418433c8
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   | sysTid=2940 nice=-6 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074430292
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=413 stm=91 core=0
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at com.android.org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:27)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
01-06 15:36:38.489: I/dalvikvm(2940):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-06 15:36:38.489: E/dalvikvm(2940): VM aborting
01-06 15:36:38.489: A/libc(2940): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00000b7c (code=-6), thread 2940 (acr.browser)
```

I would normally have assumed that I did something wrong in my `onHideCustomView` or `onShowCustomView` but my code appears fine and worked on Jelly Bean. In fact, when I take the old code I was using for Jelly Bean, set the TargetSdk to 18 and play the video, `onHideCustomView` is called when the video finishes and there are no errors. As soon as I switch it to TargetSdk 19, it isn't called and just crashes with the above error. I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

Below, you can find my `onShowCustomView` and `onHideCustomView` code as that is the only place I imagine there could be an error. There are no new methods in KitKat that tell the WebView when a video has finished.

```
    @Override
    public void onShowCustomView(View view, int requestedOrientation, CustomViewCallback callback) {
        // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one

        if (mCustomView != null) {
            callback.onCustomViewHidden();
            return;
        }
        view.setKeepScreenOn(true);
        mOriginalOrientation = getRequestedOrientation();
        FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
        mFullscreenContainer = new FullscreenHolder(this);
        mFullscreenContainer.addView(view, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);
        decor.addView(mFullscreenContainer, COVER_SCREEN_PARAMS);
        mCustomView = view;
        setFullscreen(true);
        mCurrentView.getWebView().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mCustomViewCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onHideCustomView() {
        if (mCustomView == null && mCustomViewCallback == null)
            return;
        mCurrentView.getWebView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mCustomView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
        setFullscreen(false);
        FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
        decor.removeView(mFullscreenContainer);
        mFullscreenContainer = null;
        mCustomView = null;
        mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
        // Show the content view.
        setRequestedOrientation(mOriginalOrientation);
    }
```

Thanks for any help anyone can give me.

Comment: Perhaps this is the 'FullScreen API' that isn't enabled in the WebView on API 19? https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview

Comment: @MorrisonChang Maybe, but then I would think they would have deprecated `onShowCustomView` and `onHideCustomView`. A look at the documentation shows that those methods are used exclusively for video, whereas the Fullscreen API seems to be something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar crash log as yours but it was because I tried to do a `fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();`  When I switched it to `popBackStack()` (not immediately), it worked fine.

So here's some code I tested with webChromeClient that works without any crashes on fullscreen youtube videos.

```
    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
            {
                webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                mCustomViewContainer = new FrameLayout(MainActivity.this);
                mCustomViewContainer.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                mCustomViewContainer.addView(view);
                ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).addView(mCustomViewContainer);

            }

            @Override
            public void onHideCustomView() {
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, I tested your code for `onHideCustomView` and it didn't cause the crash, so I decided to comment out lines in my onHideCustomView until it worked and I found the suspect line.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer, but I also posted the full code I'm using in an answer, since just using your code doesn't quite cover everything I needed.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I had one small error in my `onHideCustomView` method... Apparently putting

```
mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
```

in your onHideCustomView() method causes a crash on KitKat, which is odd, because I got this code directly from the source code from the Android browser. Anyway, for anyone wondering, the complete code for onHideCustomView is below.

```
@Override
public void onHideCustomView() {
    if (mCustomView == null && mCustomViewCallback == null)
        return;
    mWebView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    mCustomView.setKeepScreenOn(false);
    setFullscreen(false);
    FrameLayout decor = (FrameLayout) getWindow().getDecorView();
    decor.removeView(mFullscreenContainer);
    mFullscreenContainer = null;
    mCustomView = null;
    setRequestedOrientation(mOriginalOrientation);
}
```

Comment: I can confirm that removing `mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();` fixes the problem.